# How to log rotate attribute in transform using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, rotation, transform

How to log the value of rotate attribute using d3.js. 
For example `<path transform="translate(315.51970228390724 335.28984670867146) rotate(-41.811111262071016)"></path>`
I want to get value -41.811111262071016 in console.log()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In d3 it's easily done using `d3.transform()`:

```js
var myPath = d3.select("path");
var value = d3.transform(myPath.attr("transform")).rotate;
console.log(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<path transform="translate(315.51970228390724 335.28984670867146) rotate(-41.811111262071016)"></path>
```

**Note**: this only works in d3 version 3.