# D3.js How to get value of transform attr

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transform

I have a small question. In my application I'm using d3.js. And I need to get the values of transform attribute.
I found the same question [How to log rotate attribute in transform using d3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582076/how-to-log-rotate-attribute-in-transform-using-d3-js)
But I am using a newer version of the library.
How can I get it?
Because:

```
<g class='myclass' transform='translate(30, 0)'>

...

d3.select('.myclass').attr('transform')
```

return the string.

```
translate(30, 0)
```

(I need to get only numbers 30 and 0)I didn't find any functions for this. I can get values using regex, but I think it too much in this case. There must be some normal way to get these values. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `<g>` element [implements](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#InterfaceSVGGElement) the [`SVGGraphicsElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement) interface it features a `.transform` property that allows access to the [`SVGAnimatedTransformList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedTransformList) containing the transformations on that element. Given that there is only one translation like in your code it can be accessed like this:

```
d3.select("g").node()
  .transform          // get the animated transform list
  .baseVal            // get its base value
  .getItem(0)         // get the first transformation from the list, i.e. your translate
  .matrix             // get the matrix containing the values
```

The [`.matrix`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGTransform#properties) property is of type [`SVGMatrix`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGMatrix) and contains the values for the translation of the group element in its `e` and `f` properties.

Have a look at the following demo to see it in action:

```js
const translate = d3.select("g").node() // get the node
                    .transform          // get the animated transform list
                    .baseVal            // get its base value
                    .getItem(0)         // get the first transformation from the list, i.e. your translate
                    .matrix             // get the matrix containing the values
                    
console.log(`Translate x: ${translate.e}, y: ${translate.f}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
<svg>
  <g transform='translate(30, 0)'></g>
</svg>
```